# How hexdump is converted to x86 assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86, hexdump

How could the output be `ADD` and `MOV` operation? How could it works as `ADD` and `MOV` operation?

```
ORG 100h

a0 DW  14A0h
a1 DW  0201h
a2 DW  1506h
a3 DW  0201h
a4 DW  1606h
a5 DW  0201h
a6 DW  1706h
a7 DW  0301h
a8 DW  1806h
a9 DW  0C301h 

a12 DB 25
a13 DB 15
a14 DB 32
a15 DB 27
a16 DW 448
```

Answer (score 4):

Very easily. If you assemble this source as a flat binary, and then disassemble it, you get the following output :

```
00000000  A01401            mov al,[0x114]
00000003  02061501          add al,[0x115]
00000007  02061601          add al,[0x116]
0000000B  02061701          add al,[0x117]
0000000F  03061801          add ax,[0x118]
00000013  C3                ret
00000014  190F              sbb [bx],cx
00000016  201B              and [bp+di],bl
00000018  C0                db 0xc0
00000019  01                db 0x01
```

This was done using `nasm` and its sister disassembler, `ndisasm`.